# The probability of among the $12$ months in the year there are $4$ months containing exactly $5$ birthdays and $8$ containing exactly $1$ birthday?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $28$ people, what is the probability that, among the $12$ months in the year there are $4$ months containing exactly $5$ birthdays and $8$ containing exactly $1$ birthday?

I know I should use combinatorics somehow, but have no clue how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have 12 boxes and you are going to throw 28 balls into them.

1. Step 1. Choose 4 boxes (that will subsequently receive 5 balls). You can do that in $$\dbinom{12}{4}$$ ways.
2. Step 2. Now you want to calculate the probability that 5 balls land in each of these 4 and 1 ball in each of the remaining 8. You can say without loss of generality (due to step 1) that these are the boxes 1 to 4. The probability that a ball lands in any given box is equal to $1/12$. So you can use the [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with parameters $$p_1=p_2=\ldots=p_k=1/12$$ and $n=12$, $x_1=\ldots=x_4=5$ and $x_5=x_6=\ldots=x_{12}=1$, that is $$\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!} p_1^{x_1} \cdots p_k^{x_k}=\frac{28!}{\underbrace{5!\ldots5!}_{4 \text{ times}}\cdot\underbrace{1!\ldots1!}_{8 \text{ times}}}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^{5+\ldots+5+1+\ldots+1}=\frac{28!}{5!^4}\cdot \frac{1}{12^{28}}$$

Combining the two steps (the probability calculated in the second step and the fact that the 4 months can be choosen in $\dbinom{12}{4}$ ways) we have that the required probability is equal to $$\dbinom{12}{4}\cdot\frac{28!}{5!^4\cdot12^{28}}$$